# Insert data with different languages with one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE statuses 
    (
     id int, 
     lang int, 
     name varchar(30)
    );

ALTER TABLE `statuses` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `lang`) ;
ALTER TABLE  `statuses` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

This table holds some data which might be in different languages. Therefore I want every row which corresponds to the same data but in different languages to have the same `id` but different `lang`. This way the dual key is unique. I want to use the following query to insert and update values.

```
INSERT INTO statuses (id, lang, name) 
VALUES (null,1,'Third'),(null,2,'Trzeci') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name)
```

It works fine if I want to update the values, but it breaks when I want to actually insert something because the autoincrement feature puts different values in `id` column for every newly created row.

Here you can check SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62fbfd/1

Is it possible to correct my table structure or my sql query to do the job, or should I use multiple queries first to insert first row to indicate new `id` and after that insert the rest of the rows with this newly created `id`? I prefer to use just one query so that's why I ask here.

Comment: You can use MyISAM instead of InnoDB... and amend the PK to (lang,id)... or maybe I misunderstand your intention

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention :) PK is amended to lang,id in both cases and in both it works the same way (doesn't work)

Comment: It definitely works differently in MyISAM than in InnoDB - but neither may be what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem this way (by using two queries, but one fairly simple and with the function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b400ae/1

```
INSERT INTO statuses (id, lang_id, name) VALUES (null,(SELECT lang_id FROM languages LIMIT 1),'');
INSERT INTO statuses (id, lang_id, name) VALUES 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(),1,'Third'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(),2,'Trzeci'),(LAST_INSERT_ID(),3,'Terzo')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your schema to this:

```
CREATE TABLE statuses 
(
 id int, 
 lang int, 
 name varchar(30)
);

ALTER TABLE `statuses` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`id`, `lang`) ;

ALTER TABLE  `statuses` CHANGE  `id`  `id` INT;
```

Will that do what you want? The inserts worked when I tried them in your sqlfiddle...

You could solve your id issue (if you need auto_increment) by having another table that contains just the auto_increment values you need. So you insert into that table, get and id and then use that id in your inserts. But you cannot use auto_increment and then use the same id on several rows. If that makes any sense...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can use another table for that, I just wanted to see if it's possible without that.
Btw. I changed my structure to the one you provided and it didn't work, can you show me your fiddle?

Comment: I just used your fiddle with the above table structure...what error do you get?

Comment: its just still the same, the third added node have two different `id`s (3 and 4)

Comment: Your third node's `id`s are both `null` which is not my intention

Comment: Yes i know, but since you cannot have auto_increment AND have the same id on several rows, you need to find another solution to the null problem, for example by using another table which keeps track of some auto_incremented value which you then use as the id in your statuses table.